# USB windows xp final USB access issues

Tags: windows-xp, usb

I basically understand you C++ people, Please do not get distracted because I'm writing in Delphi.

I have a stable USB Listing method that accesses all my USB devices
I get the `devicepath`, and this structure:

```
TSPDevInfoData = packed record
  Size: DWORD;
  ClassGuid: TGUID;
  DevInst: DWORD; // DEVINST handle
  Reserved: DWord;
end;
```

I get my `ProductID` and `VenderID` successfully from my `DevicePath`
Lists all USB devices connected to the computer at the time 
That enables me to access the registry data to each device in a stable way.

What I'm lacking is a little direction

1. Is friendly name able to be written inside the connected USB Micro chips by the firmware programmer? (I'm thinking of this to identify the device even further, or is this to help identify Bulk data transfer devices like memory sticks and camera's)
2. Can I use SPDRP_REMOVAL_POLICY_OVERRIDE to some how reset these polices
   What else can I do with the registry details.
3. Identifying when some one unplugs a device The program is using (in windows XP standard)
   I used a documented windows event that did not respond. 
   Can I read a registry value to identify if its still connected?
4. using CreateFileA (DevicePath) to send and receive data
   I have read when some one unplugs in the middle of a data transfer its difficult clearing resources.
5. what can IoCreateDevice do for me and how does one use it for that task

This two way point of connection status and system lock up situations is very concerning.
Has some one read anything about this subject recently?

My objectives are to 
1. list connected USB devices

2. identify a in development Micro Controller from everything else
3. send and receive data in a stable and fast way to the limits of the controller
4. No lock up's transferring data

Note I'm not using any service packs

I understand everything USB is in ANSI when windows xp is not and .Net is all about ANSI
(what a waste of memory)

I plan to continue this project into a .net at a later date as an addition.

MSDN gives me Structures and Functions and what should link to what ok but say little to what they get used for.

What is available in my language Delphi is way over priced that it needs a major price drop.

Comment: It sounds like you are basically asking 8 questions in 1 here.  I think you should split it up in to multiple questions.  For each question, show us what you have tried and explain why it isn't working for you.  I could probably help you with a lot of this stuff, but for now my advice is to learn more about the SetupAPI and WinUSB: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff550897(v=VS.85).aspx    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff540196.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I found the registry DEVICE_INSTALL_STATE with :-

InstallStateInstalled        = 0,
  InstallStateNeedsReinstall   = 1,
  InstallStateFailedInstall    = 2,
  InstallStateFinishInstall    = 3

I ask the question of how fast is the updated response and if their is a better way to do this

Lex Dean